# Copy statically allocated string into dynamically allocated one

Tags: string, memory-management, forth

I was following an [example](http://thebeez.home.xs4all.nl/ForthPrimer/Forth_primer.html#toc-Chapter-3), trying to explain to myself what it does:

```
: place                                   \ ptr len ptr2
    2dup                                  \ ptr len ptr2 len ptr2
    >r >r                                 \ ptr len ptr2
    char+                                 \ ptr len (ptr2 + 1)
    swap                                  \ ptr (ptr2 + 1) len
    chars                                 \ ptr (ptr2 + 1) (len * char)
    cmove                                 \ --
                                          \ from to        how-many 
    r> r>                                 \ ptr2 len
    c! ;                                  \ len = ptr2 ???
\ s" Hello! " name place
```

It all made sense, until the last instruction... where did I go wrong?

**EDIT:**

I've added some tracing:

```
: place                    \ ptr len ptr2                |
    2dup    cr .s          \ ptr len ptr2 len ptr2       | <5> 16490736 5 2126333248 5 2126333248  
    >r >r   cr .s          \ ptr len ptr2                | <3> 16490736 5 2126333248               
    char+   cr .s          \ ptr len (ptr2 + 1)          | <3> 16490736 5 2126333249               
    swap    cr .s          \ ptr (ptr2 + 1) len          | <3> 16490736 2126333249 5               
    chars   cr .s          \ ptr (ptr2 + 1) (len * char) | <3> 16490736 2126333249 5               
    cmove   cr .s          \ --                          | <0>                                     
                           \ from to        how-many     |
    r> r>   cr .s          \ ptr2 len                    | <2> 5 2126333248  ok
    c! ;                   \ ptr2 = len ???              |
\ s" Hello! " name place
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first part of Will Hartung's answer is correct.

The string representation that is being used is as he described, namely a character count and then the actual string.

So in your example `c!` is storing the length of the string in the the first cell of the memory that starts with `ptr2`.

So if you wanted to retrieve your string you would only need to know the address, you could then fetch from that address to get the length n, and the fetch n chars starting at the address + 1.

Comment: Sorry it took me forever to reply. Yes, now I understood where my error was. I thought that moving data between stacks was fifo, but it's lifo, so I understand what happened, now.

Comment: Not to worry! I'm glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

in Forth, at least in this specific case, Strings have their length specified at the START of the String in memory. In C, for example, Strings are stretches of bytes terminated by a 0. In Forth, and in other languages such as Pascal, Strings have an associated length with them, and typically, as in this case, the length is at the beginning of the String.

So, for the String "HELLO", the bytes would look like

```
05 H E L L O
```

And the start of the string points at the byte with the 5 in it.

Your code locates the string, skips past the length (that first `char+`), then primes it for the `cmove`, which does the work.

At the end, it copies the length in to the start of the new String.

You example use of `place` is wrong, as you do not specify the length of the copy. This needs the length as the second argument on the stack.

So, your example should be:

```
s" Hello! " 7 name place  \ 7 because of the space after the Hello!, the quote is the
                          \ delimiter, not the space. The leading spaces are ignored
```

The odd part about this is that in theory there's no need to pass the length to the word, it's already there in the String. You would specify the length if you wanted to copy a subset.

You could look at it this way as well. Given `place` as it is, you could write a simple word:

```
: copy-string ( string-src dest -- )
    >r                          \ string-src 
    dup                         \ string-src string-src
    c@                          \ string-src length
    <r                          \ string-src length dest
    place ;
```

So:

```
s" Hello! " name copy-string
```

Then, you could do:

```
: type-string ( string-src ) 
    dup           \ string-src string-src
    c@            \ string-src length
    type ;        \ type out the string, type requires addr and length
```

So:

```
create name 10 allot
s" Hello! " name copy-string
name type-string
```

Comment: You probably want to go over the example again. It's not "my use of the example", I copied it as is from the one in the linked page. I also tested it, and it worked as advertised... Also, maybe this got you confused, in the comments I've written near the code, the top of the stack is to the right (rightmost element would be taken first from the stack).

Comment: Actually, they way you have written it, I'm getting an "invalid memory address" error.